# No Axis Named 1 for Object Type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> when trying to create stacked bar chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using DataFrame 'Gender' which currently outputs:

```
Loan_Status    N    Y
Gender               
Female        37   75
Male         150  339
```

I have the following code but I am getting the error: 'No Axis Named 1 for Object Type '

```
Gender=pd.crosstab(train['Gender'],train['Loan_Status'])
Gender.div(Gender.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(4,4))

ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Hoping someone can help me out :)

Comment: Code seems fine, what version of pandas are you using? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: using 0.23.4 pandas, to add on to this i'm running it on a jupyter notebook in case that changes anything

Comment: I've ran your code in jupyter notebook with pandas 0.24.2 and it worked fine

Comment: I tried the code with collab and it seems to work fine, must have been an issue with the jupyter notebook pandas I was using